# Why the last read appends extra characters when using BufferedReader and CharBuffer?

Tags: java

When I run the following code, the output is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678901234`.

Why is the bit `1234` appended to the final string even though the last read should only contain 6 characters,  that is `567890`?

How does the line `(reader.read(dest)` work and where does the last bit come from?

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    CharBuffer dest = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"));
      while (reader.read(dest) > 0) {
        dest.rewind();
        content.append(dest.toString());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(content.toString());
  }
```

Comment: For the solution, you can use `dest.flip();` instead of `rewind`. It will change the limit of the buffer to the current position, then set the cursor at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the third step, your character buffer `dest` contains `uvwxyz1234`.

When you read the remaining `567890`, you overwrite first six characters of the buffer. Which results in `5678901234`.

Answer (score 2):

The "why" is already answered, now for a solution, you can simply change the call of [`Buffer.rewind`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind%28%29) to [`Buffer.flip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip%28%29)

> Flips this buffer. The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero. If the mark is defined then it is discarded.

```
while (reader.read(dest) >= 0) {
    dest.flip();
    content.append(dest.toString());
}
```

THis will to the same as `rewind`, but before that, it will change the limit to the current position. That way, when you only read the last 6 character, the limit will be set at 6 and `toString` will only gave you a `String` of 6 character, not 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out to understand answer given by @lexicore. Should be self explanatory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputs = { "abcd1234", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678901234" };
    int[] sizes = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    read(sizes[2], inputs[0]);
}

public static void read(int size, String input) {
    CharBuffer dest = CharBuffer.allocate(size);
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(input));
        while (reader.read(dest) > 0) {
        dest.rewind();
        System.out.println("Content:" + content);
        content.append(dest.toString());
        System.out.println("String read:" + dest.toString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(content.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String `1234` comes from your previous read.

Comment: This might be not the most elaborate answer ever but it is a correct answer and it does not deserver the downvotes.